# Reshaping a dataframe every nth column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, reshape

I have two datasets. After merging them horzontally, and sorting the columns with the following code, I get the dataset below:

df=

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 5.2 | 6.5 |
| 3.3 | 7.6 |

df_year=

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 2014 | 2014 |
| 2015 | 2015 |

```
df_all_cols = pd.concat([df, df_year], axis = 1)
sorted_columns = sorted(df_all_cols.columns)
df_all_cols_sort = df_all_cols[sorted_columns]
```

| X | X | Y | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.2 | 2014 | 6.5 | 2014 |
| 3.3 | 2015 | 7.6 | 2015 |

I am trying to make my data look like this, by stacking the dataset every 2 columns.

| name | year | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.2 | 2014 | X |
| 3.3 | 2015 | X |
| 6.5 | 2014 | Y |
| 7.6 | 2015 | Y |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

- Apply [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to both `dfs` before feeding them to [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). The result at this stage being:

```
       0     1
0 X  5.2  2014
  Y  6.5  2014
1 X  3.3  2015
  Y  7.6  2015
```

- Next, use [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort on the original column names (i.e. `"X, Y"`, now appearing as `index level 1`), and get rid of `index level 0` ([`df.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html)).
- Finally, use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=False` to insert index as a column and rename all the columns with [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

```
res = (pd.concat([df.stack(),df_year.stack()], axis=1)
       .sort_index(level=1)
       .droplevel(0)
       .reset_index(drop=False)
       .rename(columns={'index':'Variable',0:'name',1:'year'})
       )

# change the order of cols
res = res.iloc[:, [1,2,0]]

print(res)

   name  year Variable
0   5.2  2014        X
1   3.3  2015        X
2   6.5  2014        Y
3   7.6  2015        Y
```